# Codeception "Your browser does not support HTML5 video"

Tags: codeception

Getting an intermittent error when running acceptance tests using codeception it says

`Your browser does not support HTML5 video`

Full error

```
 Test  tests/acceptance/separateTestsCest.php:tryToTest
 Step  See "actions"
 Fail  Failed asserting that  on page /index.php?module=Users&action=Login
--> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
```

I'm not sure why it does that intermittently, if I view the actions in real time using **VNC viewer** I do see the video on the screen just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My "super beautiful" solution is to remove the video block, if someone has a better answer i'll happily accept it

> ```
> public function removeVidBlock() {
>     $this->executeJS(
>     'var myobj = document.getElementById("myVideo");
>     myobj.remove();');
> }
> ```

I put this in `AcceptanceTester.php` and call it on the page where I need to remove the video via `$I->removeVidBlock();`